# Magento 2 - Get Stock Update Observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer, magento2.4

My observer is not getting product information, this line is always printed

> $this->logger->info('Product object is always null.');

```
<?php
namespace Custom\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class StockUpdate implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $productRepository;

    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * StockUpdate constructor.
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     */
    public function __construct(
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $this->logger->info('Stock item saved.');
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();

        // $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $this->logger->info('Event Data: ' . json_encode($product->getData(), true));

        $dataObject = $observer->getEvent()->getData('data_object');
        $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('item');
        $name = $observer->getEvent()->getData('name');

        $this->logger->info('Data Object: ' . json_encode($dataObject, true));
        $this->logger->info('Item: ' . json_encode($item, true));
        $this->logger->info('Name: ' . json_encode($name, true));

        if ($product === null) {
            $this->logger->info('Product object is always null.');
            return;
        }
```

And my events.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after">
        <observer name="custom_module_stock_update" instance="Custom\Module\Observer\StockUpdate" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Snippet of output:

```
[2023-08-21T10:02:05.503413+00:00] report.INFO: Stock item saved. [] []
[2023-08-21T10:02:05.503751+00:00] report.INFO: Event Data: ["data_object","item","name"] [] []
[2023-08-21T10:02:05.503888+00:00] report.INFO: Data Object: {} [] []
[2023-08-21T10:02:05.504012+00:00] report.INFO: Item: {} [] []
[2023-08-21T10:02:05.504136+00:00] report.INFO: Name: "cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after" [] []
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the class `\Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\Item` (which triggers your even), there is no "Product" object sent.

The object retrievable is "Item" :

```php
    /**
     * Parameter name in event
     *
     * In observe method you can use $observer->getEvent()->getItem() in this case
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_eventObject = 'item';
```

You can only get the item in this observer :

```php
$item = $observer->getEvent()->getItem();
```

If you need to retrieve the product object, you will need to load it from the Product Repository, using `$item->getProductId()`.